# How do you wrap setTimeout in a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to run a test suite for an object that returns a promise.  I want to chain several actions together with short timeouts between them.  I thought that a "then" call which returned a promise would wait for the promise to be fulfilled before firing the next chained then call.

I created a function

```
function promiseTimeout (time) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){resolve(time);},time);
  });
};
```

to try and wrap setTimeout in a Promise.

Then in my test suite, I am calling something like this ...

```
    it('should restore state when browser back button is used',function(done){
      r.domOK().then(function(){
        xh.fire('akc-route-change','/user/4/profile/new');
      }).then(promiseTimeout(2000)).then(function(t){
        xu.fire('akc-route-change','/user/6');
      }).then(promiseTimeout(10)).then(function(t){
        expect(xu.params[0]).to.equal(6);
        history.back();
      }).then(promiseTimeout(10)).then(function(){
        expect(xu.params[0]).to.equal(4);
        done();
      });
    });
```

I can put a breakpoint on the first `xh.fire` call and a second one on the `xu.fire` call and would have expected a two second gap when a continues from the first breakpoint to the second.

Instead it reaches the second breakpoint immediately, and the value of `t` at that point is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing is akin to `setTimeout(fn(), 1000)` instead of `setTimeout(fn, 1000)`, what `then` takes is a function that returns a promise and not a promise.

Comment: Also, you can `return` promises from `it`, no need to use `done`

Comment: Don't understand what you mean I just changed the setTimout call to `setTimeout(resolve,time,time);` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

TL;DR - you've wrapped setTimeout in a promise properly, the issue is you are using it improperly

```
.then(promiseTimeout(2000)).then
```

will not do what you expect. The "signature" for .then is `then(functionResolved, functionRejected)`

> A promise’s then method accepts two arguments:
>
> promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)
>
> Both onFulfilled and onRejected are optional arguments:
>
> - If onFulfilled is not a function, it must be ignored.
> - If onRejected is not a function, it must be ignored.

source: https://promisesaplus.com/#point-21

You are not passing a function to then

Consider the way you are doing it:

```
Promise.resolve('hello')
.then(promiseTimeout(2000))
.then(console.log.bind(console))
```

vs how it should be done:

```
Promise.resolve('hello').then(function() { 
    return promiseTimeout(2000)
}).then(console.log.bind(console))
```

The first outputs 'hello' immediately

The second outputs 2000 after 2 seconds

Therefore, you should be doing:

```
it('should restore state when browser back button is used', function(done) {
    r.domOK().then(function() {
        xh.fire('akc-route-change', '/user/4/profile/new');
    }).then(function() {
        return promiseTimeout(2000);
    }).then(function(t) {
        xu.fire('akc-route-change', '/user/6');
    }).then(function() {
        return promiseTimeout(10);
    }).then(function(t) {
        expect(xu.params[0]).to.equal(6);
        history.back();
    }).then(function() {
        return promiseTimeout(10);
    }).then(function() {
        expect(xu.params[0]).to.equal(4);
        done();
    });
});
```

Alternatively:

```
it('should restore state when browser back button is used', function(done) {
    r.domOK().then(function() {
        xh.fire('akc-route-change', '/user/4/profile/new');
    }).then(promiseTimeout.bind(null, 2000)
    ).then(function(t) {
        xu.fire('akc-route-change', '/user/6');
    }).then(promiseTimeout.bind(null, 10)
    ).then(function(t) {
        expect(xu.params[0]).to.equal(6);
        history.back();
    }).then(promiseTimeout.bind(null, 10)
    ).then(function() {
        expect(xu.params[0]).to.equal(4);
        done();
    });
});
```

### EDIT: March 2019

> Over the years, things have changed a lot - arrow notation makes this even easier

Firstly, I would define promiseTimeout differently

```
const promiseTimeout = time => () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time, time));
```

The above returns a function that can be called to create a "promise delay" and resolves to the time (length of delay). Thinking about this, I can't see why that would be very useful, rather I'd:

```
const promiseTimeout = time => result => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time, result));
```

The above would resolve to the result of the previous promise (far more useful)

But it's a function that returns a function, so the rest of the ORIGINAL code could be left unchanged. The thing about the original code, however, is that no values are needed to be passed down the .then chain, so, even simpler

```
const promiseTimeout = time => () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
```

and the original code in the question's `it` block can now be used *unchanged*

```
it('should restore state when browser back button is used',function(done){
  r.domOK().then(function(){
    xh.fire('akc-route-change','/user/4/profile/new');
  }).then(promiseTimeout(2000)).then(function(){
    xu.fire('akc-route-change','/user/6');
  }).then(promiseTimeout(10)).then(function(){
    expect(xu.params[0]).to.equal(6);
    history.back();
  }).then(promiseTimeout(10)).then(function(){
    expect(xu.params[0]).to.equal(4);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Got it.  Like the second approach, although I just tried both and both work I also tidied up promiseTimeout - like the comment made in response to Benjamin Gruenbaum

Comment: Yes, this works fine, but minor point, in the first code fragment, doing `function() { return promise.Timeout(n); }` over and over again seems excessively verbose, would like to just write `makePromiseTimeout(n)` instead.

Comment: Same issue [worth reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38956175/444255), with a bit more ES6-Syntax and /w and w/o original promise pass-through.

Answer (score 8):

To make a timeout which works as you want, write a function which takes a delay, and returns a function suitable for passing to `then`.

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Promise.resolve() . then(timeout(1000)) . then(() => console.log("got here"););
```

However, it is likely that you will want to access the resolved value of the promise leading into the timeout. In that case, arrange for the function created by `timeout()` to pass through the value:

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return value => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms));
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Promise.resolve(42) . then(timeout(1000)) . then(value => console.log(value));
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  Taking away the new ES6 notation, and renaming timeout to promiseTimeout the first part of your answer seems identical to my original question which doesn't work.  Where is the difference?

Comment: My `timeout` function returns a function which returns a promise. Your original one returns a promise. `then` requires a function--passing it a promise as you were doing will do nothing at all.

Comment: Sorry for previous comment - I now understand what you are saying.  I find this new ES6 notation a bit difficult to understand without careful thought and effectively translating it back to the Javascript I understand.

Comment: This is very neat but in my code, the test returns success before the timeout fires and the actual test runs. Test failure generates an error. I changed it to: 'return Promise.resolve(42).then...' and now the test correctly reports success / failure.

Comment: Why is the first `Promise.resolve().then` needed? Why not just let your `timeout` return `new Promise(...)`?

Answer (score 7):

This has already been answered above, but I feel this could be done easily with:

```
const setTimeoutPromise = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
```

`setTimeoutProise` function accept wait time in `ms` and passes it down to the `setTimeout` function. Once the wait time is over, the resolve method passed down to the promise is executed.

Which could be used like this:

```
setTimeoutPromise(3000).then(doSomething)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    // wait for 50 ms.
    setTimeout(function(){resolve()}, 50);
});
console.log("This will appear after waiting for 50 ms");
```

This can be used in an async function and the execution will wait till given interval.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This is great for doing the await style fetch chains, so if you drop this above your const res = await fetch( someURL ) it delays it like a charm, no extra fluff.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for adding delays to `Promise`s **without having to predefine or `import` a helper function** (that I personally like best) is to extend the property of the `Promise` constructor:

```
Promise.prototype.delay = function (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.setTimeout(this.then.bind(this, resolve), ms);
  });
}
```

I'm leaving out the `reject` callback since this is meant to always `resolve`.

**DEMO**

```js
Promise.prototype.delay = function(ms) {
  console.log(`[log] Fetching data in ${ms / 1000} second(s)...`);

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.setTimeout(this.then.bind(this, resolve), ms);
  });
}

document.getElementById('fetch').onclick = function() {
  const duration = 1000 * document.querySelector('#duration[type="number"]').value;

  // Promise.resolve() returns a Promise
  // and this simply simulates some long-running background processes 
  // so we can add some delays on it
  Promise
    .resolve('Some data from server.')
    .delay(duration)
    .then(console.log);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="duration" type="number" value="3" />
  <button id="fetch">Fetch data from server</button>
</div>
```

Or if you need it to also be `.catch()`-able, here is when you need the second argument (`reject`). Note that the `catch()` handling will also occur after the delay:

```js
Promise.prototype.delay = function(ms) {
  console.log(`[log] Fetching data in ${ms / 1000} second(s)...`);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.then(resolve).catch(reject);
    }, ms);
  });
}

document.getElementById('fetch').onclick = function() {
  const duration = 1000 * document.querySelector('#duration[type="number"]').value;

  Promise
    .reject('Some data from server.')
    .delay(duration)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log); // Promise rejection or failures will always end up here
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="duration" type="number" value="3" />
  <button id="fetch">Fetch data from server</button>
</div>
```