# How to add delay to promise inside then

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, promise

```
fetch() {   
    return axios.get('/rest/foo')
        //.then(response => {throw new Error(response)}) // Uncomment to test network error
        //.then( <<add delay here>> ) // Uncomment to simulate network delay
}
```

How do I add delay in the latter then block, so it will wait specified amount of time before passing control to the fetch callers then blocks?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Return a promise from the `then` handler that waits:

```
.then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)))
```

If you want to "pass through" the value of the promise, then

```
.then(x => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(x), 1000)))
```

To avoid this boilerplate everywhere, write a utility function:

```
function sleeper(ms) {
  return function(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(x), ms));
  };
}
```

then use it as in

```
.then(sleeper(1000)).then(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, worked well for me with a minor modification for my case: within an async function, you can just write: `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))`

Comment: Starting from Node.js 16, you can also use the [Timers Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timers_promises_api).

Answer (score 23):

This is one of the rare situations you create a new promise:

```
fetch() {   
    return axios.get('/rest/foo')
        .then(value => new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(value);
                }, delayInMilliseconds);
            })
        );
}
```

But rather than a one-off, I'd have (in fact, do have) a utility function:

```
function wait(ms, value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
}
```

Then:

```
fetch() {   
    return axios.get('/rest/foo')
        .then(value => wait(delayInMilliseconds, value));
}
```

---

Here's `wait` with TypeScript types (thanks [MEMark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268091/memark)!):

```typescript
function wait<T>(ms: number, value: T) {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
}
```

Comment: With TypeScript typings: `function wait<T>(ms: number, value: T) {
    return new Promise<T>((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
  }`