# How to run a function with a delay from inside axios then

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I'm, a bit new to vue so please be kind. I have a simple push call I want to run 2 seconds after a user uploads a photo to my app. I'm trying to do this inside my axios "then" but it happens instantly. I want to make this take place after 2 seconds. How can I use setTimeout to accomplish this?

I've seen the answer here...[How to add delay to promise inside then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956121/how-to-add-delay-to-promise-inside-then?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But my mind is melting trying to understand it.

```

```
  axios.put(`${process.env.KITTY_URL}/api/v1/cats/${this.singleCat.id}/`,formData,{
          onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
            console.log('Upload progress: ' + Math.round(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100) + '%')
          }
        })
          .then(response => {
            response.status === 200 ? this.showSuccess = true : this.showDanger = true;
            this.singleCat = response.data;
            // NOTE: set a timer to run this line 2 seconds after success response
            setTimeout(function() { this.$router.push('/login'); }, 2000)<---WHAT SHOULD THIS LOOK LIKE?
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.showDanger = true;
          })
```

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to bind the context. Easiest way to do this is just with an arrow function. So you would just need to change that line to this:

```
setTimeout( () => this.$router.push('/login'), 2000);
```

Another way is to use async/await:

```
let response = await axios.put(...);
setTimeout( () => this.$router.push('/login'), 2000);
```

Though you won't have as nice of error handling this way: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1086

Similar question: [Accessing VUE JS's data from Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216998/accessing-vue-jss-data-from-axios)