# Refactoring to async with SetTimeout Vuex Action

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

So I have this call to an API in my actions at the Vuex Store, however I want to refactor it with a setTimeout, just to give my initial state time to commit(about a second). 
here's the function

```
Authenticate: ({commit})=>{
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
      commit('auth_request')
      return Axios.get(util.functions.pathFromScript('authenticate.php'),{params:params() }).then(resp =>{
        state.logged_in = true
        state.restricted =false
        const data = resp.data
        const session_id = data.session_id
        console.log(session_id) 
        localStorage.setItem('data',data)
        localStorage.setItem('session_id',session_id)
        commit('auth_success', params, data,session_id)
        resolve(resp)
      })
    })
  }
```

so basically I can't figure it out where to add the async,and the timeout here. Any help would be appreciated A LOT! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

So theres already two answers to this question.

This one:
`.then(resp => setTimeout(resolve, 1000){...`

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956121/how-to-add-delay-to-promise-inside-then)

and:

`.then(promiseTimeout(2000)).then`

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843091/how-do-you-wrap-settimeout-in-a-promise)