# How to create setTimeoutAsync with this specific interface?

Tags: javascript, promise

This is not a duplicate of this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843091/how-do-you-wrap-settimeout-in-a-promise).

Instead I want the API or interface to work as follows:

```
setTimeoutAsync(1000).then(()=>{
  console.log('1 second passed');
});
```

I want to use new Promise() as from my understanding this is what the constructor is primarily used for:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
})
```

and setTimeout();

```
setTimeout(func, time, funcArg1);
```

Comment: All snippets proposed in the other question do exactly what you are asking for?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the reason(s) you think the duplicate does not apply to your question.

Comment: To clarify @JonasWilms's comment, the *answers* to that question deal with that OP's desire to use the wrapped timeout a specific way in *promise chaining*, but the OP's version of `promiseTimeout` has the exact interface you've specified in this question already. To reiterate: The first snippet in the dupe target is a wrapped timeout with the exact interface you want.

Comment: A better dupe target is probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956121/how-to-add-delay-to-promise-inside-then?noredirect=1&lq=1 because the answers to that question answer this question well. I have no idea why that one is marked a dupe of the promise-chaining question, it's quite misleading.

Comment: @klaycon good suggestion, changed the target.

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, what I was trying to clarify was that the first snippet in the first dupe's question text, as well as the top answer to the second dupe both include a function almost identical to the one answered here, and both serve as fine answers to the stated question. Indeed neither had passing arguments but to be fair that was an extra detail that wasn't known at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
function setTimeoutAsync(interval, value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, interval, value));
}
```

Usage:

```
setTimeoutAsync(1000).then(() => console.log('1 second passed'));
// or with an argument
setTimeoutAsync(1000, 1).then(n => console.log(`${n} second passed`));
```

Or using async/await:

```
async function main() {
  const n = await setTimeoutAsync(1000, 1);
  console.log(`${n} second passed`);
}
```

This solution is limited to 1 value argument, because of `resolve` only accepting 1 argument, and you can't retrieve the handle from setTimeout to clear it in case you need that. Thanks to @PatrickRoberts for pointing that out.

If you need more then 1 value argument I recommend passing an array with your values or an object containing key-value pairs.

Comment: or `await setTimeoutAsync(1000)` if inside an `async` function.

Comment: @NikKyriakides Good suggestion. I assumed this question wasn't a dup so I answered quickly.

Comment: @J.M. FYI, `resolve()` only accepts a maximum of one argument so the rest parameter seems rather silly. I'd suggest something like `function setTimeoutAsync(delay, value = undefined) { return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, delay, value); }); }`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Good catch, I edited the answer.

Comment: @A1rPun I think you misunderstood my point. It doesn't particularly matter to me whether you pass the arguments through `setTimeout()`, or directly to `resolve()` within a closure. What I'm saying is that there's no point in making it variadic because a specification-compliant promise will drop all but `args[0]`, e.g. `new Promise(resolve => resolve(1, 2, 3)).then((...args) => console.log(...args))` will log `1`, not `1 2 3`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes you are right, I made a quick assumption and while I'm testing my current implementation I see your point very clearly.

Comment: For cancellation, you could potentially monkeypatch the promise instance like this: `function setTimeoutAsync(delay, value) { let timeout; return Object.assign(new Promise(resolve => { timeout = setTimeout(resolve, delay, value); }), { cancel () { clearTimeout(timeout); } }); }`, though based on the nature of the question I don't think this was even a concern, and I don't recommend the practice of creating promises that never resolve, since it's often code smell and can lead to confusing or unexpected behavior in higher-level promise chains that follow this underlying promise.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's a creative monkey patch! I want to try to get as much functionality out of this answer though. Maybe you could `reject` the promise when the timeout gets cancelled, I think that doesn't smell but the implementation will be some dirty code.

Comment: @A1rPun `function setTimeoutAsync(delay, value) { let rejectImpl; return Object.assign(new Promise((resolve, reject) => { rejectImpl = reject; setTimeout(resolve, delay, value); }), { cancel (reason) { rejectImpl(reason); } }); }` in that case. It's safe to let the timeout occur anyway, because once a promise settles, it can't _re_-settle, so continuations (e.g. `.then()`, `.catch()`, `.finally()`) will only be called once, depending on how the promise settles _first_ (i.e. fulfillment or rejection).

Comment: Looking back at that atrocity of an implementation in my last comment though, I'm inclined to say that's a failure to separate concerns. For cancellation, I'd suggest a completely separate (and composable) API akin to C#'s `TaskCompletionSource`: `class PromiseCompletionSource { constructor () { this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { this.resolve = resolve; this.reject = reject; }); } }` then with your current implementation, `var pcs = new PromiseCompletionSource(); pcs.promise.then(console.log, console.error); setTimeoutAsync(1000, 1).then(pcs.resolve);` so `pcs.reject()` cancels.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I really like your idea of keeping it SOLID. I <3 you monkey-patches as well but I wouldn't recommend it in production code :)