# Is it possible to create new Promise object in Angular 1.7?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, promise, ecmascript-5

I have an application that currently uses Angular 1.7 and we have an `IHTTPPromise` (updateCase) where we then process the code on the `then()` method after it has resolved

Before the first `then()` I want to chain another `then()` to set a waiting period of x milliseconds

I cannot use `setTimeout()` just in that then as that does not return a Promise.

In Angular 1.7, how can I create a new Promise to contain the setTimeout and then resolve and allow me to have chained then statements?

```
this.caseService.updateCase(updateCaseRequest)
//***WANT TO ADD A WAIT HERE
    .then(
    response => {
        this.showUpdateComplete();
        this.getCases();
        this.$scope.selectedCase = selectedCase;
    })
}
```

Comment: By using the Promise constructor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you wrap setTimeout in a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843091/how-do-you-wrap-settimeout-in-a-promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the $timeout Service:

```
this.caseService.updateCase(updateCaseRequest)
.then( response => {
    return this.$timeout( (_ => response) , delay );
}).then( response => {
    this.showUpdateComplete();
    this.getCases();
    this.$scope.selectedCase = selectedCase;
})
```

The return value of calling `$timeout` is a promise, which will be resolved when the delay has passed and the timeout function, if provided, is executed.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delay requests or other things more often by using something within the then chain, you could use the following:

```
/** Can be used within a then-chain to delay the next then in the chain ;) */
export const delayPromise = (ms: number, value: any) => new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms); });
```

```
this.caseService.updateCase(updateCaseRequest)
    .then(res => delayPromise(res, 1000)) // Wait 1 second
    .then(response => {
            this.showUpdateComplete();
            this.getCases();
            this.$scope.selectedCase = selectedCase;
        }
    );
```

Edit: cannot be used in angularjs context - see comments

Comment: with the delayPromise constm, I get the message "Promise only refers to a type but is being used as a value here"

Comment: are the argument inter-changed? `delayPromise(1000,res)`?

Comment: `Promise` and `setTimeout` should not be used/suggested. Angularjs has specific services for that (`$q` and `$timeout`)

Comment: The ES6 Promises returned by `new Promise` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.